# Is a question asking for textbook referrals on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I've already asked a question of this nature and I'd like to ask another. I'm looking for a precalculus text that includes a significant discussion of complex numbers, especially graphing in the complex plane and the connection between the unit circle, complex numbers, and the trigonometric functions. Is a questions asking for such books on-topic?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Question on selecting textbooks and alike are on-topic. But one should take care to ask a specific question, rather than something too broad and/or primarily opinion based.

The specific question you propose seems fine to me.

Examples that would *not* be good include:

- What is the best textbook on Abstract Algebra? (too opinion based, especially as no criteria are specified)
- What textbooks for  Calculus are available? (too broad)

General SE references on this include:

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Not everything there applies verbatim, but there are some good points there that also seem pertinent to the type of question you ask about.